# Downloaded shader is not applied

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Shader download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S54II-mbT3MH88k49-HtNdCMok8lCk2t/view

When I open the .blend file it loads normally and the model appears, however the Shader is not applied to the model

---

Note: it's supposed to be like this[image]

Comment: Are you in rendered view ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine to me, are you sure that you are in render view?
[image]

Comment: Since it works for EEVEE, do you have any idea why it doesn't work in Material Preview?  I took a quick look at the material but I can't see a reason.

Comment: The reason is quite obvious... looks in node setup what is the last thing going into material output... it is emission node, emission node like this won't be visible in the material preview, only in render view because there is no way you can see emission with black color (it makes just full black silhouette of the object

Comment: doh.  I should have known that. thanks.